# Direct Airside Transit Visa

Tags: transit, datv

Is (Special) direct airside transit (DATV) the correct application form for a transit visa? The form seems excessively long and detailed considering that the applicant isn't entering the country, and even includes a section asking where they are staying in the UK which isn't applicable. Is it possible that either I have the wrong link, or I should be ignoring some of the questions?

Comment: Are you going to clear UK immigration or not? Is your trip on a single ticket (meaning you don't have to pick up luggage)?

Comment: How would we know whether you have the wrong link when you're not showing which link you have?

Comment: I've recently completed the application for a UK transit visa, and although mine isn't airside, all I will be doing is traveling between Heathrow & Gatwick. For my address in the UK I just gave the address of Heathrow airport. Didn't seem to be a problem for UK Visas and Immigration in New York as my visa was issued after 3 days.